# Why do I need to push the same value +4 when printing a float?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, fasm

I have been trying to print out a float value in FASM for a pretty long time until I finally found a solution, it worked but, why is it like that? On a C program I made the assembly code generated by x64dbg was something like this:

```
mov dword ptr ss:[esp+1C],eax
fld st(0), dword ptr ss:[esp+1C] ;<--- focusing on these 2
fstp qword ptr ss:[esp+4],st(0)  ;<---
mov dword ptr ss:[esp],c.404000
call <JMP.&printf>
```

I thought the fact `fld` loaded the float value into st(0) and `fstp` loaded the st(0) value on an address, basically, quite obvious so I used to try things like:

```
format PE
entry start

include '%include%\win32a.inc'

section '.text' code readable executable
start:
fld dword ptr dVal
fstp qword ptr dVal2
push msg
call [printf]
call [getchar]
call [exit]

section '.idata' import data readable
library msvcrt, 'msvcrt.dll'

import msvcrt, printf, 'printf'\
exit, 'exit', getchar, 'getchar'

section '.bss' data readable writeable
dVal2 dq ?

section '.data' data readable
msg db '%f',10,13,0
dVal dq 3.14
```

Which after many tries, rendered me crashes or results like 0 or random numbers that have nothing to do with what I wanted. However, after so much research I finally found out that I could simply do something like

```
...
section '.text' code readable executable
start:
fld dword ptr dVal
fstp qword ptr dVal2
push dword ptr dVal2+4
push dword ptr dVal2
push msg
call [printf]
call [getchar]
call [exit]
...
```

or just

```
...
section '.text' code readable executable
start:
push dword ptr dVal+4
push dword ptr dVal
push msg
call [printf]
call [getchar]
call [exit]
...
```

Why do I need to push the same value +4 before printing a float value? And what essentially is the REAL4 value from MASM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` function can only print 64 bit floats (double).  Such a double comprises 8 bytes.  Either push this value onto the stack by storing to the stack from the FPU:

```
sub     esp, 8           ; make space for the double
fstp    qword ptr [esp]  ; store double into that space
push    OFFSET msg
call    [printf]
```

or push to the stack in two steps of 4 bytes each:

```
fstp    [dVal2]          ; store double to global/static variable
push    dword ptr [dVal2+4]    ; push high half of double
push    dword ptr [dVal2]      ; push low half of double
push    OFFSET msg
call    [printf]
```

Note that as the stack grows down, we have to push the high 4 bytes before the low 4 bytes.  Two separate pushes are required as you can only push 4 bytes at a time, but a double is 8 bytes.

---

Assuming you declared `dVal2` as a qword like in the question, that will imply a size for `fstp [dVal2]`.  [`fstp` can also](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/fst:fstp) convert to dword (float) or store as the raw 10-byte internal format used in x87 registers.  That's why we needed `fstp qword ptr [esp]` since `[esp]` doesn't imply an operand size.

As always, to access storage near a data label with a size different from the first item after that label, MASM needs you to override the size or it will complain about a mismatch, thus `push dword ptr [dVal2+4]`, because `push qword ptr` is only available in 64-bit mode.  (Where it would be passed in XMM1 as the 2nd arg to a function.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation it was really easy and simple to understand! And sorry for making you get mixed on FASM and MASM it's just that I wanted to know what data types like REAL4, REAL8 and REAL10 meant, because whenever I searched about floating point numbers in ASM I'd always find them, which upon further research combining with what you had presented me I figured out REAL4 is a 32bit float, REAL8 is a 64bit float and REAL10 is a 80bit float (please correct me if I'm wrong). You helped me have a better idea of the difference between floats and doubles.